# Removing elements from nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to remove the element of A1 from the list B1:

How I can do that?

Thank you!

`A1= {{5, 6}, {4, 5}, {5, 4}}`

````
   B1 = {{9, 6}, {5, 6}, {6, 0}, {0, 5}, {10, 8}, {1, 2}, {10, 4}, {1, 1}, {7,
    7}, {6, 8}, {5, 3}, {6, 10}, {7, 4}, {1, 8}, {10, 0}, {10, 7}, {6,
    3}, {4, 0}, {9, 2}, {4, 7}, {1, 6}, {10, 8}, {7, 8}, {0, 10}, {3, 
   4}, {0, 0}, {8, 5}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}, {2, 9}, {2, 4}, {8, 4}, {7, 
   4}, {3, 6}, {7, 10}, {1, 10}, {1, 4}, {8, 0}, {8, 9}, {5, 4}, {2, 
   5}, {2, 9}, {3, 1}, {0, 6}, {10, 3}, {9, 6}, {8, 7}, {7, 6}, {7, 
   3}, {8, 9}};```
````

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) with the pattern `Alternatives @@ A1`:

```
DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ A1]@ B1
```

> ```
> {{9, 6}, {6, 0}, {0, 5}, {10, 8}, {1, 2}, {10, 4}, {1, 1}, {7, 7}, {6,   8}, {5, 3},
>  {6, 10}, {7, 4}, {1, 8}, {10, 0}, {10, 7}, {6, 3}, {4, 0}, {9, 2},
>  {4, 7}, {1, 6}, {10, 8}, {7, 8}, {0, 10}, {3, 4}, {0, 0}, {8, 5},
>  {6, 0}, {2, 9}, {2, 4}, {8, 4}, {7, 4}, {3, 6}, {7, 10}, {1, 10}, 
>  {1, 4}, {8, 0}, {8, 9}, {2, 5}, {2, 9}, {3, 1}, {0,  6}, {10, 3}, 
>  {9, 6}, {8, 7}, {7, 6}, {7, 3}, {8, 9}}
> ```